# Excel live data counter (DDE Server)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, dde

I'm using DDE server to import live data on excel on two columns, the data changes every second.

What im currently doing is i have live data on Cell A1 and live data on Cell B1 
on Cell C1 i have the following formula

```
=A1=B1
```

Which is suppose to be true, but sometimes the result is false (as cell A1 doesn't match cell B1)

I want to calculate how many times "false" is the result in C1

My problem is its a live data and changes almost every second, and my result should be accumulated. 
Does anyone have any suggestion on how can it be done on excel?

Thanks,

Comment: automatic calculation is on, it calculates per second but i need to count how many this instance happens

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Give this a try :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Dim Count As Long
Dim KeyCells As Range

Set KeyCells = Range("C1")

Count = 0

If IsEmpty(Range("D1").Value) = False Then
    Count = Range("D1").Value
End If


    If KeyCells.Value = False Then
        Count = Count + 1
        Range("D1").Value = Count
    End If

End Sub
```

**Note :** Here D1 Cells will ***Save*** the counted value, Change the cells if needed ... This code will count how much time "False" are returned ..

Credit to tim for worksheet_calculate()

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the [Worksheet_Calculate event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.calculate(even)). Each time a calculation occurs, this event is triggered.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim i As Long

'Check if cell C3's value is FALSE
If Cells(1, 3) = False Then
    'Loop through all customer properties of the workbook
    For i = 1 To CustomProperties.Count
        'Check if there is a property named Counter
        If CustomProperties.Item(i).Name = "Counter" Then
            'If there is, add 1 to the property's value and exit the sub
            CustomProperties.Item(i).Value = CustomProperties.Item(i).Value + 1
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i

    'If the customer property was not found, 
    'add it and add the value 1 to it
    CustomProperties.Add Name:="Counter", Value:=1
End If

End Sub
```

This code adds a [custom property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.customproperties) to the workbook file. This removes clutter from the worksheet by storing the counter in the file data instead.

The counter's value can be checked with `CustomProperties.Item(1).Value` if it's the first property in the file (which is likely, unless you have added more)